# Forwarding using mapping.findForward in Struts 1.2

Tags: javascript, struts-1

```
public class MyAction extends Action
{   
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {

        String status="success";
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        System.out.println("My Action---setting key value");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("key1","check");

        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9080/FamiliarPortal/jsp/inicio.jsp");
        return mapping.findForward(status); 

    }
}
```

In `Struts-config.xml`, the following is added:

```
<action path="/myAction" type="iusa.ubicacel.actions.MyAction" validate="false" >
         <forward name="success" path="/jsp/inicio.jsp"/>       
</action>
```

In `web.xml`, the following is added:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetFAP</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>iusa.ubicacel.actions.map.GetFAP</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetFAP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetFAP</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In `inicio.jsp`, the following is added:

```
<BODY onload="requestXML('<%=reqURL %>');">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 1000px; height:700px"></div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

The function `requestXML` is as follows:

```
function requestXML(reqURL) 
{   
    alert("calling requestXML"+reqURL);
    var url = "../GetFAP?requestURL=" + reqURL;
    alert("calling requestXML"+url);
    xmlhttpUbi = FAPXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttpUbi.open("POST", url, true); // async
    alert("after calling");
    xmlhttpUbi.onreadystatechange = obtainFAPLocation;
    xmlhttpUbi.send(null);
}
```

The above code is not calling the GetFAP servlet when using `mapping.findForward`. But when I used `response.sendRedirect("entire jsp path")` it is calling the servlet.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The forward you show has nothing to do with "GetFAP", I don't know why you'd think it would.

Comment: the forward is mapped to inicio.jsp in struts-config.xml.Onload of incio.jsp calls requestXML() function which calls GetFAP

Comment: Then the problem is likely your use of a relative URL, but it's difficult to say. You can debug this, you know, by using the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: Yes.When I changed it to " var url = "GetFAP?requestURL=" + reqURL;" it worked.But I really don't understand why.The same thing worked when I didnt use Struts.What could be the reason?Also what would be the difference between "./GetFap" and "../GetFap" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative URL instead of an absolute URL.

When you render the JSP directly, the `../GetFAP` mapping works because you *must* move "up" a level up from the `/jsp` directory.<sup>1</sup>

When you render the JSP from an action, you're moving a level up from the *action's* path, i.e., there's no more `/jsp` directory in the URL to move up *from*.

This is among the many reasons why using relative paths can be a bad idea.

---

<sup>1</sup> JSP files should live in the `WEB-INF` directory to avoid direct client access.